# Passing grouped linq object to view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, razor

Im trying to pass a linq list object from my controller to my view. The linq object contains a grouping which is throwing some sort of error. I just want to display the grouped objects in a view. The linq statement works perfectly but displaying the statement doesn't! any help would be greatly appreciated!

controller

```
        public ViewResult StudentAttendanceForYear(int id)
    {

        DateTime finDate = System.DateTime.Today;
        DateTime strtDate = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-6);


        var chosenStudent = (from t in db.ClassInstanceDetails.Include("Student")
                                 where (t.Attendance == false) && (t.StudentID == id)
                                 && (t.ClassInstance.Date > strtDate) && (t.ClassInstance.Date < finDate)
                                 group t by new { t.ClassInstance.Date.Year, t.ClassInstance.Date.Month, t.ClassInstance.Date.Day } into grp
                                 select new
                                 {

                                     absentDate = grp.Key,
                                     numAbsences = grp.Count(t => t.Attendance == false)

                                 }).ToList();



        return View(chosenStudent.ToList());
    }
```

view

I tried changing my view to

```
@model IEnumerable<System.Linq.IGrouping<object, FYPSchoolApp.DAL.ClassInstanceDetail>>
```

but still no luck, and I keep getting the following error:

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType7`2[<>f__AnonymousType6`3[System.Int32,System.Int32,System.Int32],System.Int32]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Linq.IGrouping`2[System.Object,FYPSchoolApp.DAL.ClassInstanceDetail]]'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't try to pass anonymous types into the view as a model.

What you need is a ViewModel:

```
public class AbsentCountViewModel
{
   public DateTime absentDate { get; set; }
   public int numAbsences { get; set; }
}
```

Then change your query to select into your viewmodel

```
var chosenStudent = 
   (from t in ...
   group t by new 
   { 
           t.ClassInstance.Date.Year, 
           t.ClassInstance.Date.Month, 
           t.ClassInstance.Date.Day 
   } into grp
   select new
   {
       absentDate = grp.Key,
       numAbsences = grp.Count(t => t.Attendance == false)
   }).ToList()
   // you need to do the select in two steps 
   // because EF cannot translate the new DateTime
   .Select(item => new AbsenctCountViewModel
   {
       absentDate = new DateTime(item.absentDate.Year, 
                                 item.absentDate.Month, 
                                 item.absentDate.Day)
       numAbsences = item.numAbsences
   }).ToList();

return View(chosenStudent);
```

And finally you can access your result in the view with the @model:

```
@model List<AbsenctCountViewModel>
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply, I'm relatively new to all this! I've create the VIewModel and inputted your code but now im getting this error "Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities." Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: Sorry, that is caused by the `new DateTime(...` and there are multiple ways to solve it... I will update my answer.

Comment: That fixed it! Thanks VERY VERY much! Its safe to say I would never have solved that on my own!